# How to fix "ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in UPDATE"

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to update a column based on a few conditions, using a calculation.

The theory I am using is as follows;
If column1 contains 'string' then 'calculation of column2 and column3' gets put in column4.

The calculation works, but I am struggling to find a way to UPDATE a column by using these IF conditions and a SUM.

I have searched stack and postgres documentation. I see that there are a number of aggregate errors but none specifically solve this problem.

```
UPDATE table1
SET "column4" = CASE
        WHEN "column1" ILIKE '%Y%' THEN SUM(CAST("column2" AS 
                numeric(4,2))) / SUM(CAST("column3" AS numeric(4,2)))
        END;
```

The error which I am getting is as follows;

ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in UPDATE
LINE 7: WHEN "column1" ILIKE '%Y%' THEN (SUM(CAST("...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Perform your calculations in a [Common Table Expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html):

```
    WITH cte_avg AS (
        SELECT SUM(CAST("column2" AS numeric(4,2))) / SUM(CAST("column3" AS numeric(4,2))) AS avg
        FROM table1
    )
    UPDATE table1
    SET "column4" = cte_avg.avg
    FROM cte_avg
    WHERE "column1" LIKE '%Y%'
```

Comment: Thank you, this achieves the result I was looking for!

Comment: Kudos for the answer. A kind note that ```WHERE "column1" LIKE '%Y%'``` could be also replaced by ```WHERE tab1.column1=cte_avg.column1```, where column1 is some sort of an index/key column. In case some1 wants to update every id of table1